# Value join is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, T)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This function seems valid for my IDE:

```
def zip[T, U](rdd1:RDD[T], rdd2:RDD[U]) : RDD[(T,U)] = {
    rdd1
      .zipWithIndex
      .map(_.swap)
      .join(
        rdd2
          .zipWithIndex
          .map(_.swap))
      .values
}
```

But when I compile, I get :

> value join is not a member of
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, T)] possible cause: maybe a semicolon
>   is missing before `value join'?
>             .join(

I am in Spark 1.6, I have already tried to import *org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD._*
and the code inside the function works well when it is directly used on two RDDs outside of a function definition.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you change the signature:

```
def zip[T, U](rdd1:RDD[T], rdd2:RDD[U]) : RDD[(T,U)] = {
```

into:

```
def zip[T : ClassTag, U: ClassTag](rdd1:RDD[T], rdd2:RDD[U]) : RDD[(T,U)] = {
```

This will compile.

**Why**? `join` is a method of `PairRDDFunctions` (your `RDD` is implicitly converted into that class), which has the following signature:

```
class PairRDDFunctions[K, V](self: RDD[(K, V)])
  (implicit kt: ClassTag[K], vt: ClassTag[V], ord: Ordering[K] = null)
```

This means its constructor expects *implicit* values of types `ClassTag[T]` and `ClassTag[U]`, as these will be used as the value types (the `V` in the `PairRDDFunctions` definition). Your method has no knowledge of what `T` and `U` are, and therefore cannot provide matching implicit values. This means the implicit conversion into `PairRDDFunctions` "fails" (compiler doesn't perform the conversion) and therefore the method `join` can't be found.

Adding `[K : ClassTag]` is shorthand for adding an implicit argument `implicit kt: ClassTag[K]` to the method, which is then used by compiler and passed to the constructor of `PairRDDFunctions`.

For more about ClassTags and what they're good for see [this good article](https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/overcoming-type-erasure-in-scala-8f2422070d20#.7g4tof8ke).