# Spark reduceByKey with generic types (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, types, scala-generics

I am trying to create some simple custom aggregate operators in Spark using Scala.

I have created a simple hierarchy of operators, with the following super-class:

```
sealed abstract class Aggregator(val name: String) {
  type Key = Row  // org.apache.spark.sql.Row
  type Value

  ...
}
```

I also have a companion object, which constructs the appropriate aggregator each time. Observe that each operator is allowed to specify the Value type it wants.

Now the problem is when I try to call `combineByKey`:

```
val agg = Aggregator("SUM")
val res = rdd
    .map(agg.mapper)
    .reduceByKey(agg.reducer(_: agg.Value, _: agg.Value))
```

The error is:

```
value reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(agg.Key, agg.Value)]
```

For my needs, `Value` can either be a numeric type or a tuple, hence its no bounds definition. If I replace the `Value` type declaration with:

```
type Value = Double
```

in `Aggregator` class, then everything works fine. Therefore, I suppose that the error is relevant to `reduceByKey` not knowing the exact `Value` type in compile time.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: Missing `ClassTags`? Check for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/39993041/9613318

Comment: @user9613318 I have seen that, but my RDD gets created inside the method (thus the method is not type parameterised). Is there any way to manually create implicit ClassTags?

Comment: `implicitly` might help. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/47644051/9613318

Comment: (Note: changed `combineByKey` to `reduceByKey`) - I can't seem to be able to get around this. I think that I need a way so that `reduceByKey` picks the actual type of `agg.Value` at runtime. Even with `implicitly` as in the answer above, it still does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RDD` cannot be implicitly converted into `PairRDDFunctions`, because all the implicit `ClassTag`s for keys and values are missing.

You might want to include the class tags as implicit parameters in your `Aggregator`:

```
sealed abstract class Aggregator[K: ClassTag, V: ClassTag](name: String) {
  implicit val keyClassTag: ClassTag[K] = implicitly
  implicit val valueClassTag: ClassTag[V] = implicitly
}
```

or maybe:

```
sealed abstract class Aggregator[K, V](name: String)(implicit kt: ClassTag[K], vt: ClassTag[V]) {
  implicit val keyClassTag: ClassTag[K] = kt
  implicit val valueClassTag: ClassTag[V] = vt
}
```

or maybe even:

```
sealed abstract class Aggregator(name: String) {
  type K
  type V
  implicit def keyClassTag: ClassTag[K]
  implicit def valueClassTag: ClassTag[V]
}
```

The last variant would shift the responsibility for providing the `ClassTag`s to the implementor of the abstract class.

Now, when using an aggregator `a` of type `Aggregator[K, V]` in a `reduceByKey`, you would have to make sure that those implicitly provided class tags are in the current implicit scope:

```
val agg = Aggregator("SUM")
import agg._ // now the implicits should be visible
val res = rdd
.map(agg.mapper)
.reduceByKey(agg.reducer(_: agg.Value, _: agg.Value))
```

Comment: It worked, thanks so much for this! I opted for way 3 as I wanted to make the caller K/V-agnostic. In each implementor I now have `override type V = SomeType` and `override implicit def valueClassTag = ClassTag(ClassOf[V])`. Marked as accepted answer.